# Is there an alternative to deprecated e.which in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Im new to JavaScript event handling, I would like to trigger an event upon mousemove and left-click on a div element. My current implementation is to check that `e.which == 1` when I trigger the mousemove event function. However, I have read that the e.which property is now deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which). My code:

```
div.addEventListener("mousemove", myEventFunction)

function myEventFunction(e){
    if (e.which == 1){
       //do something
    }

}
```

Is there any alternative to perform this operation?

Comment: @KevinKloet Nopes. It's for keyboard events. For mouse, it's `button`. Also, `keycode` is deprecated.

Comment: didn't see the mouse event, my bad

Comment: Sure.. No worries. @KevinKloet

Comment: use the e.key instead to check

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Are you sure? What does it give? Dude, this is a `MouseEvent`! What you are telling is a `KeyboardEvent`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`event.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) if it is gonna be a mouse event.

> The `MouseEvent.button` read-only property indicates which button was pressed on the mouse to trigger the event.

```
function myEventFunction(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if ("buttons" in e) {
        return button;
    }
    var button = e.which || e.button;
    return button;
}
```

The above function returns the `button` value.

Comment: e.buttons works for me! Thank you so much for the prompt reply.

Comment: Yes I noticed the difference between them. Thank you again.